# you cannot edit your response error when using FormResponse.getEditResponseUrl

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms, onsubmit

I have created a form where submitters **cannot** edit after submission. I have attached an [`on form submit`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit_4) event and in that function I email the [`FormSubmission.getEditResponseUrl()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response#geteditresponseurl) value.

```
function onSubmit(e) {
  MailApp.sendEmail(e.response.getRespondentEmail(), "form test", e.response.getEditResponseUrl());
}
```

The function works -- it sends the email with the URL. But when they click on the link they get the error:

> You cannot edit your response
>
> Responses to this form cannot be edited.
>   Try contacting the owner of the form if you think this is a mistake.

My understanding is that anyone with the URL generated by `getEditResponseUrl()` let's them edit the `FormResponse` even if the `Form` is set to **not** let them edit.

Is there something I am doing wrong? I'm going crazy looking at this.

Comment: See the following issue in the [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/118596850)  Click the star in order to show that you are affected.

Comment: `anyone with the URL generated by getEditResponseUrl() let's them edit the FormResponse even if the Form is set to not let them edit.` How is that logical?

Comment: @TheMaster That's what the documentation says. And I added a comment to the below accepted answer with why/how that functionality would be used. It's unfortunate they took it away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [#11 reply](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/118596850#comment11) by a Googler to the [issue linked](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/118596850) by Alan Wells

> The engineering team determined that the root cause of this issue was
>   an intentional change around how edit URLs work. Although we rolled
>   back this change temporarily, we will roll it forward again soon.
>
> Specifically, today you can use an edit URL even if the form has the
>   "Edit after submit" setting turned off. We don't think this respect's
>   the form owner's intent and made a change to prevent edits unless that
>   setting was enabled.
>
> In our first attempt at this change we directed users to a blank edit
>   page, which was confusing and made people assume there was a bug. The
>   next time we roll this change forward we will instead redirect users
>   to an error page that makes the situation more clear.
>
> When this change rolls forward, it will likely break some scripts and
>   add-ons again.

The same post includes what to do:

> There are two things that can be done to prevent this:
>
> 1) Enable the "Edit after submit" setting manually on forms that you
>   wish to with this feature.
>   2) In your Apps Script code, use the
>   setAllowResponseEdits() method to enable that setting when you know
>   your code requires it.

Comment: Thanks! That is unfortunate though. I want it so a user can't edit the form after submission (and change their answers) unless the post-submission validation script finds a problem. Then it would generate that URL and notify the user. I need to figure out a better way to do this.